# CSS3 transition for border

Tags: html, css

I am trying  to add a transition for the red border when you Hover off on the list item but the transition work only when you hover on.

Is it possible to add a transition for the red border so that it slide out when you hover off?
here is the code http://jsbin.com/ewilix/3/edit

Comment: From my knowledge, a pure CSS cannot do this task. You might need to use jQuery: hover, and fadeIn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the same properties for the initial left border as in it's hover state, but with 0 width:

```
#conteneur-menu2 ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 230px; 
    transition: all 2s;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: red;
    border-left-width: 0px;
}
```